# IO backend error in the xarray for netcdf file

Tags: python, io, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to open a .netcdf file using xarray and it is showing this error. I am unable to resolve this error and I have found no such solution to resolve this error. I have tried with different versions of Anaconda and Ubuntu but the problem persists.

> ValueError: did not find a match in any of xarray's currently installed IO backends ['scipy']. Consider explicitly selecting one of the installed backends via the `engine` parameter to xarray.open_dataset(), or installing additional IO dependencies:
> http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/getting-started-guide/installing.html
> http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/io.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your error message, it looks like you are only missing the `scipy` dependency.

I would recommend installing using `conda install` in either your terminal/command line or in Jupyter (if you use that IDE):
`conda install scipy`

If you are using a Python environment other than your base environment, ensure you are installing to the environment are using for the project by navigating there in terminal (e.g., `conda activate MYENV`), or by running that environment kernel in Jupyter.

You may need to restart the kernel if you are using Jupyter for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I then installed netCDF4 via:

```
pip install netCDF4
```

and xarray worked. Beware of dependencies!!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as well. In this matter, you need to install IO dependencies.
Based on their web site [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/getting-started-guide/installing.html) you need to install all IO related packages:

```
io = netCDF4, h5netcdf, scipy, pydap, zarr, fsspec, cftime, rasterio, cfgrib, pooch 

conda install -c anaconda netcdf4 h5netcdf scipy pydap zarr fsspec cftime rasterio cfgrib pooch
```

Comment: better would be to use `xarray`'s list of i/o packages to install: eg: `pip install "xarray[io]"`

Answer (score 1):

This error message can also be triggered when simply having an error in the path to the file to be opened. For example this results in the same/similar error (even with the netcdf backend installed):

```
import xarray as xr
xr.open_dataset("this_file_does_not_exist.nc")
```

So before (re)installing any packages, make sure to check whether the input to xr.open_dataset() is correct.

Comment: Thanks! This comment helped me. My filename was stored inside of a list, rather than just being a string, and it gave me an error about backends when I tried to load it. If you're using glob to locate a file, don't make this same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> conda install scipy

solves the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).